# elementary os loki pantheon mail with Office 365

Tags: pantheon-mail, office

anyone using pantheon mail with office 365? I can't make it work.

Regards
Vitor Jr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have my Office365 work email setup.  Adding a signature is optional and not required in any way.

[image: Office365 Settings]